# Restrict NFS to only run on certain cores

Tags: systemd, cpu, cgroups

I have an application that likes to use the very first core in a core complex. For example, assuming CPU has CCX of 4, it would run the load on core 0,3,7,11,…. This process is time sensitive and quickest execution is the goal.

In knowing this, id like to configure the system to avoid interrupting this process. I've attempted to specify a `CPUAffinity=0 3 7 11` in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` which appears to work for userspace. Then i set `CPUAffinity=0-128` to allow i back in the application service file. However, NFS is outside userspace and runs as a kernel process. It seems this process is then interpreting the application process by still having access to all the cores, ignoring what i defined in `system.conf`.

In short, how can i ensure the only process executing on `0 3 7 11` is the application process?

Comment: This old Linux kernel discussion might be relevant to the subject: https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/00000140efbcb701-c26320b3-f434-4538-bc80-8e92fed6f303-000000@email.amazonses.com/#t